# PHP Manipulating HTML from string

Tags: php, html

I'm reading in an HTML string from a text editor and need to manipulate some of the elements before saving it to the DB.

What I have is something like this:

```
<h3>Some Text<img src="somelink.jpg" /></h3>
```

or

```
<h3><img src="somelink.jpg" />Some Text</h3>
```

and I need to put it into the following format

```
<h3>Some Text</h3><div class="img_wrapper"><img src="somelink.jpg" /></div>
```

---

This is the solution that I came up with.

```
$html = '<html><body>' . $field["data"][0] . '</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$domNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

// Remove Img tags from H3 and place it before the H# tag
foreach ($domNodeList as $domNode) {
    if ($domNode->parentNode->nodeName == "h3") {
        $parentNode = $domNode->parentNode;
        $parentParentNode = $parentNode->parentNode;

        $parentParentNode->insertBefore($domNode, $parentNode->nextSibling);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: [ all you need is love ] http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the question with the answer, but for good measure, here it is again in the answers section.

```
$html = '<html><body>' . $field["data"][0] . '</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$domNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

// Remove Img tags from H3 and place it before the H# tag
foreach ($domNodeList as $domNode) {
    if ($domNode->parentNode->nodeName == "h3") {
        $parentNode = $domNode->parentNode;
        $parentParentNode = $parentNode->parentNode;

        $parentParentNode->insertBefore($domNode, $parentNode->nextSibling);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a preg_replace

```
// take a search pattern, wrap the image tag matching parts in a tag
// and put the start and ending parts before the wrapped image tag.
// note: this will not match tags that contain > characters within them,
//       and will only handle a single image tag
$output = preg_replace(
    '|(<h3>[^<]*)(<img [^>]+>)([^<]*</h3>)|',
    '$1$3<div class="img_wrapper">$2</div>',
    $input
);
```

Comment: note2: this won't move the image out of the heading, better to use DOM here

Comment: Oops, missed that part of the question.  Thank you.